# Azure ACS beginner approach

Tags: azure, acs

I know there are a lot of questions about Azure ACS, but I want to ask a more general one:

Should I use ACS, or it's not worth the effort? :)

What I want is a secure WebService in Azure that will be called from 2 places: a mobile app and another service inside Azure. Users will never access this webService directly.

Thanks

**Update:**
I don't care much about the identity of the user that is behind my mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the specific scenario, you say that users will not access the service dicrecly, but presumably it is the user who will use the mobile and/or web app.

Thinking of authentication and authorisation - if all you need to do is identify that you're coming from your own appilcation, than there are defintiely leaner approaches. simple certificate based solution would do, or even username/password based solution.

If, however, you wish to use the identity of user beheind the app to drive the authentication and authorisation for the service, than you do need to worry about the user's identity, and of course you can manage it yourself, but this is where the ACS comes very handy in that it lets you leverage one or more existing identity providers, which makes it easier for you and the user.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not worth it.

ACS is great for managing user identity on your behalf: in other words, for allowing your users to make identity claims.

If your Web service needs to know about your users' identities then it's definitely worth the (small) effort to implement, as it takes care of much of the work for you.

If your Web service doesn't know about user identity, and there's no external endpoint defined for the service -- then, yes, I'd not bother with ACS either.